# Rails 3 RESTful web services with json

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, web-services, rest, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am looking for any basic Ruby on rails tutorial that uses RESTful web services with json, If somebody can throw  a very basic app that implement those technologies i would appreciate, I have tried to google but i couldn't find anything.Also if you could give me a real world scenario where we would actually use that ,would be even more helpful.Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

For those coming to this question from google like myself, take a look at some of the tutorials [here](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=37), they were a great help for me.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveResource is the simple way to implement restful web service's in rails

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-railsactive/

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html

Comment: Please explain your answer link alone answers amy become outdated if the link expires.

Answer (score 0):

This could be helpful also

is a tutorial of Rails 4 with MongoDB

http://moredevideas.wordpress.com/2013/04/26/rails-4-with-mongodb/

MongoDB is a NoSQL database. MongoDB is a document-oriented database that stores JSON documents, and is schemaless, that means that each document can have it own schema.